# xargs --max-proc split output per proc?

Tags: unix, xargs

I recently discovered the `xargs --max-procs` feature.

How can split the output of the command by proc?  Should I just create a  `mycommand --logfile $LOGFILE`, or can I do it from xargs itself?

An example (for womble):

Suppose I have script myprocessor.sh, and a list of files.  They can go in any order, but i want to keep the logging for each separate, then:

```
find $MY_FILE_TREE --print0 | xargs --null --max-procs 3 --max-args 1 --no-run-if-empty myprocess.sh
```

might be the parallel job I want to run.  If `myprocessor.sh` is mouthy, then I'd like to be able to have each invocation print to a different log.  Otherwise the stdout for each is the same, and the logs get jumbled.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: womble, I hope my added example is clear.  Please request more information if not.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by running your xargs command through a shell - this will let you redirect the output - something like this:

```
find blah -type f | xargs -I{} -P 4 -n 1 sh -c 'yourcommand --input {} > {}.output'
```

...you'll probably have to tweak it a bit - xargs replaces {} with the item/file it's working on

Comment: that replacement is a little hairy when the find output is rooted paths, but it's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ seems to be made for you, because it automatically combines the standard output from the processes correctly.

```
find $MY_FILE_TREE --print0 | parallel --null --max-procs 3 --max-args 1 --no-run-if-empty myprocess.sh ">" {}.output
```

or shorter:

```
find $MY_FILE_TREE --print0 | parallel -0 -j3 -r myprocess.sh ">" {}.output
```

Watch the intro video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

You could change your script so that on startup it'll choose a random number/text, then prefix each line with this number? Then you can later split it using grep.